# Executing an SSIS package with SQL query in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis, etl

So, I want to execute an SSIS package through an SQL query in C#.

I've simplified it as much as possible, so some of the code is lacking.

My main method looks like the following:

```cs
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ExecuteSSIS("SSISPACKAGE.dtsx");
}
```

And then we have the ExecuteSSIS method with the connection string

```cs
private static string SSISDB = "Data source=.; Initial Catalog=SSISDB; Integrated Security=SSPI;";

public static void ExecuteSSIS(string PackageName)

{

string executeLoad = @"
                    DECLARE @execution_id BIGINT

                    EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[create_execution] @package_name=N'@packageName'
                        ,@execution_id = @execution_id OUTPUT
                        ,@folder_name = N'CorrectFolderName'
                        ,@project_name = N'CorrectProjectName'
                        ,@use32bitruntime = False
                        ,@reference_id = NULL

                    SELECT @execution_id

                    DECLARE @var0 SMALLINT = 1

                    EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[set_execution_parameter_value] @execution_id
                        ,@object_type = 50
                        ,@parameter_name = N'LOGGING_LEVEL'
                        ,@parameter_value = @var0

                    EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[start_execution] @execution_id";
                           

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(SSISDB))
{
    try
    {
        SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(executeLoad, connection);
        sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@packageName", PackageName);
        sqlCommand.Connection.Open();
        sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        sqlCommand.Connection.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

The SQL query in of itself works just fine, but when I try to run the program I get the error

> "Cannot access the package or the package does not exist. Verify that
> the package exists and that the user has permissions to it."

And I'm going crazy trying to figure out why.

Comment: The package file (SSISPACKAGE.dtsx) needs to be in same folder as the c# executable or include pathname where file is located

Comment: @jdweng that has nothing to do with the problem.  The packages are stored in the SSIS catalog database, and the C# is running on some other server.

Comment: Not directly related but: `+ "Select @execution_id "` Why? This creates a resultset which your code does not retrieve. `"DECLARE @var0 smallint = 1 "` Why? This never changes - make it a literal in your code. And start using statement terminators to make your code easier to read and slightly more future-proof. Finally - don't use [addwithvalue](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Comment: I'm just following the official Microsoft Docs. 
To my knowledge, addwithvalue is what replaced SqlParameterCollection.Add - which is what Dan Guzman suggests instead.

Comment: Could be a permissions error.  Did you test with the same account?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft fixed my error. See solution in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow okay, so i fixed it. Turns out to be a simple error/miss.

```
 EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[create_execution] @package_name=N'@packageName'
```

It seems C# can't insert/find the parameter @packagename, while it's inside **' '** (Apostrophe)
So when i changed it to

```
EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[create_execution] @package_name= @packageName
```

It worked as inteended.